# NodeJS Authorize with JWT token

Tags: node.js, jwt, restful-authentication, express-jwt

I'm trying to use a JWT token to authorize the user before allowing them to GET a "welcome" page.

Here's the code for the endpoint;

```
var apiRoutes = express.Router();
apiRoutes.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
apiRoutes.use(bodyParser.json());
apiRoutes.use(verifyToken);
apiRoutes.get('/', welcome)
```

Here's the `verifyToken` function;

```
var verifyToken=function (req, res,next) {
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['token'];
     if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, config.secret, function (err, currUser) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                req.currUser = currUser;
                next();
            }
        });
    }
     else {
        res.status(401).send("Invalid Access");
    }
};
module.exports=verifyToken;
```

And here's the welcome page;

```
module.exports=function(req, res) {
    res.send('Welcome..!! Now  you are now authenticated !');
};
```

But when I try to GET the endpoint in Postman I get this;

```
 Cannot GET /
```

I've tried putting the token in Postman as parameters, as raw body JSON, in the headers, and as a form but still unable to get the welcome page. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the apiRoutes ?

Comment: The routes are called in the server.js file and                                                                     
   var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
   var app  = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' +port);
});

Comment: Don't forget that calling the apiRoutes in the server.js you should do `app.use('/', apiRoutes)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure that your middleware runs when the endpoint is called, you may put something like this:
in your server.js

```
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
```

and in your route fils

```
apiRoutes.get('/', verifyToken, welcome);
```

And remove it from the use

Comment: Though promising, that didn't seem to do it.

Comment: Heres' what worked. If you edit your answer with this I can choose it.               app.use('/api', apiRoutes); 
apiRoutes.use(verifyToken);
apiRoutes.get('/', verifyToken, welcome);

Comment: And I used /api/ as the route.

Comment: The most important is that your problem is solved :)